# Compiling PJSIP for use in iOS 5

Tags: ios, gcc, sip

I know iOS 5 is still under NDA, but I don't think this will violate their terms.

When I try to compile PJSIP for xcode for use within iOS 5, it dosen't find gcc. "Cannot find gcc for iOS 5 SDK" is the error I get. Is there any way to remedy this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your project isn't configured to use GCC!
XCode 4.2 will default to LLVM 3.0 with clang frontend (gcc command replacement)

Comment: That sounds very possible! How do I fix this?

Comment: klick on your project in the navigator, select the target -> build configuration tab and set the key "Compiler for C/C++/Objective C" to "LLVM GCC 4.2" (maybe you will have to click on "All" directly below the top tab bar)

Comment: Oh, I think I might not have explained myself clearly. What we're doing is compiling in the command line. The script to build PJSIP looks in a specific place for the GCC compiler, but with the update to the iOS 5, they've changed GCC's location. I've tried editing the script to look in the right place, but the same error occurs.

Comment: okay that will be tricky.. you should make sure you're setting CC & CXX environment variables to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2

Comment: Will try. Just to make sure I'm going to be doing the right thing, here's the full error I got:

`configure-iphone: IPHONESDK is not specified, choosing iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
ls: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin*: No such file or directory
configure-iphone error: unable to find gcc for iPhoneOS5.0.sdk. If you think you have the right gcc, set the full path in CC environment variable.`

Comment: in my installation dev tools are SDK-independent (so only one toolchain for 1 platform with multiple SDKs).. `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/` is the location for gcc

Answer (score 2):

[Changeset 3818 in the PJSIP codebase](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/3818) fixes this issue by allowing configure-iphone to find LLVM

Comment: So how to implement this ?